# Prop passed in to component is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, web

I am building an ecommerce website which includes a cart for each user. I want to pass the state of cart to a component using props

In App.js -

```html
<Header cart={cart} />
```

In Header.js -

```js
function Header({ cart }) {
  console.log(cart);
}
```

I have checked console.log(cart) in App.js and it gives me the desired and correct array of objects.

I pass in this state as a prop to Header Component and then I want to display the number of items in the cart.

But, the console.log(cart) in Header.js gives me undefined.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

App.js -->

```
function App() {
  const [{ bag }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  console.log("CART -", cart);

  useEffect(() => {
    //will only load when app component loads
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
      console.log("USER ->", authUser);

      if (authUser) {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: authUser,
        });

        db.collection("users")
          .doc(authUser.uid)
          .collection("cart")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            setCart(
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.data().id,
                image: doc.data().image,
                productName: doc.data().productName,
                productPrice: doc.data().productPrice,
              }))
            )
          );
      } else {
        dispatch({
          type: "SET_USER",
          user: null,
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/payment">
            <Header cart={cart} />
            <Elements stripe={promise}>
              <Payment />
            </Elements>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/checkout">
            <Header />
            {/* <CategoriesHeader /> */}
            <Checkout />
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/">
            <Header />
            <CategoriesHeader />
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add App.js component code in details?

Comment: Yeah sure I did

Comment: Does it really that console.log(cart) gives you desired and correct array of objects? Because is see that you print cart before db.collection (inside useEffect) get some data?

Comment: yeah....it does

Comment: I can see that you use Header multiple times both with and without card prop. Also, Header should render at least two times (before and after useEffect of its parent). Are you sure that you see the correct console.log and not some of the irrelevant ones?

Comment: Header has a return method?